# Implement survey/quiz in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox, android-radiobutton

Good evening everyone,

I'm implementing a survey(like a quiz) in an Android application. Firstly, I implemented it with no regard for the design part, but now I have to take care of it too.

The quiz is composed of multiple questions with multiple question types. The questions are shown sequentially (vertically). I implemented the survey using a RecyclerView so that I could define multiple types of questions.
For the "checkbox type questions" I used a lib called CheckBoxGroup...but now that's not viable as I have to implement the layout like this:

[image]

I thought about implementing it with a listview, and define the layout for when it is pressed and not pressed. Then set the listview to multiple choice selection mode. Any thoughts?

About single choice questions:

[image]

Should I do it the same way but with single choice selection mode?

Thank you very much in advance!